# notepad++ regular regex

Tags: notepad++

I have a document that I have opened in notepad++ that has the following line, `return 1`. I also have cases where it says `return 2` I want to be able to do a find where `!return 1`. So I want to find and count every thing that is not `return 1`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return\ [^1]
```

use above regex